# why won't a dynamic sqlite statement work but the exact same static statement will work?

Tags: python, sqlite

this is my first post on stack overflow... thanks in advance for any and all help
I am very new to programming and i created a function in Python to dynamically search an sqlite3 database rather than entering in tons of queries. i will show the code and try to explain what i intended to happen at all the stages. In short my cursor.fetchall() always evaluates to empty even when i am certain there is a value in the database that it should find.

```
def value_in_database_check(table_column_name: str, value_to_check: str):
    db, cursor = get_connection() # here i get a database and cursor connection
    for tuple_item in schema(): # here i get the schema of my database from another function
        if tuple_item[0] == "table": # now I check if the tuple is a table
            schema_table = tuple_item[4] # this just gives me the table info of the tuple
            # this lets me know the index of the column I am looking for in the table
            found_at = schema_table.find(table_column_name)
            # if my column value was found I will enter this block of code
            if not found_at == -1:
                table_name = tuple_item[1]
                to_find_sql = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE ? LIKE ?".format(table_name)
                # value_to_check correlates to table_column_name
                # example "email", "this@email.com"
                cursor.execute(to_find_sql, (table_column_name, value_to_check))
                # this always evaluates to an empty list even if I am certain that the
                # information is in the database
                fetch_to_find = cursor.fetchall()
                if len(fetch_to_find) > 0:
                    return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `?` can only be used as placeholder for values, not for names of tables or - as you try to do - columns. A likely fix (haven't tested it though):

```
to_find_sql = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE {} LIKE ?".format(table_name, table_column_name)
cursor.execute(to_find_sql, (value_to_check, ))
```

Comment: How about sql injection with this?

Comment: Thank you @Błotosmętek i feel rather slow as i tried this in multiple ways including just replacing all the `?` place holders with `{}` replacement fields. Your way did indeed work. @The Fool I am aware of sql injection attacks, but i believe it couldn't occur in this case, please correct me if i am wrong as i am very new to this. In this case the only information coming from a user field would be in the `?` at the end of the statement. the other replacement fields come from the `.schema` of the database for what ever table it is currently looking in. Please advise if there are better ways.

Comment: @TheFool thank you for the edits as well. I will keep those in mind moving forward

Comment: @Błotosmętek it turns out that the real problem was a conflict with my cursor, your solution worked because i had closed my ide. it worked the first time i tried it with your solution but didn't work the next time around. I have been adding `cursor.close()` as well as `db.close()` after all my functions that use the database and cursor. this seems to have fixed it now but i will have to do some more digging into this

Comment: @jgriff, if you have a working solution, feel free to post you own answer and accept it.

Comment: and yes, if you are aware of the injection risk and are sure no user can put values there, it may be ok. I am not sure if there are better ways, might be worth a question on its own.

Comment: @TheFool I selected his answer as the correct one as he was right about the `?` only being a place holder for values, not columns. I had more problems with my code that i didn't technically ask about in the question. Thanks again for the edits and the heads up on the sql injection attack possibility. @Błotosmętek thank you for the answer.